# Intrepret parameter starting with a hyphen as a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, argparse

I'm using `argparse` to set up the parameters for my python script.  The last parameter is an "ID number" and it can be any mix of alphanumeric characters and hyphens.

<sub>Note: The program is a downloader/decoder for MMS messages and the "ID" parameter is provided by the cell network, so I can't change what it is.</sub>

I'm having a problem where, if the ID starts with a hyphen, argparse reads it as multiple parameters instead of as a string.

Here is the `argparse` portion of my code:

```
version = "0.4 alpha"

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="MMS Viewer v{0}: An MMS Downloader and Decoder".format(version),
    epilog="https://github.com/NTICompass/mms-viewer"
)

parser.add_argument('-V', '--version', action='version', version=version)

parser.add_argument("file_or_phone", help="MMS File or phone number")
parser.add_argument("mmsid", nargs="?", help="MMS-Transaction-ID")

parser.add_argument('--debug', help="Print debugging info", action="store_true")

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-x', '--extract', help="Extract image file(s)", action="store_true")
group.add_argument('-X', '--extract-original', help="Extract original image file(s) without using PIL", action="store_true")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I run the program as such `./main.py 15555555555 abc123xyz` (you can also run it as `./main.py file.bin`).

The issue comes when the final parameter starts with hyphen, as shown:

```
./main.py 15555555555 -mTkKkr5e
```

It seems that `argparse` is reading the "-mTkKkr5e" as multiple different flags and thus gives the error:

```
usage: main.py [-h] [-V] [-p] [--debug] [-d | -x | -X] file_or_phone [mmsid]
main.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -mTkKkr5e
```

How can I fix this so that python/argparse will give me the final parameter as the string `"-mTkKkr5e"`?

Comment: Let us know if using the `--` recommended in the duplicate doesn't work for you.

Comment: @hpaulj: The `--` thing *did* actually work! :-)  `./main.py -- 15555555555 -mTkKkr5e` works perfectly!